# Unable to boot to Windows 7 or Ubuntu after multiboot setup

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, windows-xp, boot

I installed windows 7 in the C drive, then installed Ubnutu on E, and yesterday, I installed Windows XP on drive D.

I was then unable to boot into Windows 7 or Ubuntu.  I formatted drive D, but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is, that the win xp bootloader is unable to load 7 / ubuntu. The problem can be fixed by reinstalling the grub loader. I don't know if you can do this without reinstalling ubuntu, maybe there is a way.

Comment: Yes, there is: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-24113.html